# Generate Hibernate DAO with netbeans

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

I am using `hibernate` framework in my web application. I once generated `DAO` files from `eclipse` using `hibernate tool`. But in `netbeans(8.0)` IDE I dont see an `option to generate` DAO files like in eclipse. This is the window I am seeing in netbeans
Is there a third party library to generate DAO files in netbeans ?
[netbeans hibernate panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjzcW.png)

Comment: Use Spring Data, which does it for you on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to generate entity objects directly in netbeans, without plugins or third-party tool. Just select entity from database option in new option from file menu. It also automatically creates persistence.xml for you for jpa.

Comment: i created entity classes from the database and session beans for each entity. thank you for your support.